# how to not remove space in file

Tags: python-2.7

how to keep the space betwen the words?
in the code it deletes them and prints them in column.. so how to print them in row and with the space?

```
s ='[]'
f = open('q4.txt', "r")
for line in f:
    for word in line:
        b = word.strip()
        c = list(b)
        for j in b:
            if ord(j) == 32:
                print ord(33)
            if ord(j) == 97:
                print ord(123)
            if ord(j) == 65:
                print ord(91)
            chr_nums = chr(ord(j) - 1)
            print chr_nums

    f.close()
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: remove the `word.strip()` command - that's deleting the space. Then put a comma after the `print` operation to prevent a newline: `print chr_nums,`

There are several problems with your code aside from what you ask about here:

- `ord()` takes a string (character) not an int, so `ord(33)` will fail.
- `for word in line:` will be iterating over characters, not words, so `word` will be a single character and `for j in b` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the first for loop :

```
for line in f:
```

here the variable named 'line' is actually a line from the text file you are reading. So this 'line' variable is actually a string. Now take a look at the second for loop :

```
for word in line:
```

Here you are using a for loop on a string variable named as 'line' which we have got from the previous loop. So in the variable named 'word' you are not going to get a word, but single characters one by one. Let me demonstrate this using a simple example :

```
for word in "how are you?":
    print(word)
```

The output of this code will be as follows :

```
h
o
w

a
r
e

y
o
u
?
```

You are getting individual characters from the line and so you don't need to use another for loop like you did 'for j in b:'. I hope this helped you.